# ¿Cómo obtener el número máximo y mínimo entre los registros consultados?

Tags: mysql

Por ejemplo:

1. Tengo 10.000 productos registrados en la tabla productos.
2. Hago una consulta: **`select * from productos where nombre='placa de video'`**
3. Ahora lo que quiero hacer es detectar, entre los productos seleccionados el precio máximo y el precio mínimo.

Obviamente lo más sencillo es hacer 3 consultas. Pero no me parece una buena opción.

¿Cual es la manera más optima de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aplica directamente el `max` y el `min` en el `select`

Ejemplo:

```
select max(precio) as precioMaximo, min(precio) as precioMinimo
from productos 
where nombre='placa de video';
```